# Publish research with few details to promote company

Tags: publications

I've seen cases of startups publishing research with so few implementation details that it's quite difficult to recreate the results. They seem to be doing it to for the publicity and to show proof of the effectiveness of their methods without making it too easy for others to create a similar business. Now that I am considering starting a company based on my research I am curious as to how this actually works. I have the following list of questions, but feel free to answer using a single answer instead of one for each item.

1. Is it in general frowned upon in academia to publish this kind of research that is used for "marketing" your company?
2. To what degree do higher quality journals/conferences require implementation details?
3. How good credentials must the author have to be able to publish this kind of paper?

Comment: "I've seen cases of startups publishing research with so few implementation details that it's quite difficult to recreate the results". Can you provide any examples? What discipline? Where is this research published? (In premium journals / conferences) or mediocre publishing venues?

Comment: @Alexandros The [DeepMind](https://deepmind.com/research/publications/) is one of those startups (now acquired by Google) that publish quite a lot. Other IT giants such as [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/research-area/artificial-intelligence/publications/) and [Facebook](https://research.fb.com/publications/) also publish in academic venues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two basic directions that you can go in using scientific publications to promote a company:

1. You can publish in the same sort of conferences and journals as university scientists, thereby proving your technical depth and strength.  If you take this path, you will be expected to conform to the same standards of quality and depth of information as a university researcher: there is no "peer review lite" unless you go to a junk publication, which won't help your goals.
2. Many conferences explicitly have an "industrial track" or "demo session" that is explicitly designed for showing off capabilities without necessarily having to explain details, in order to better promote engagement between the academic and commercial sides of research.  These often have some sort of "extended abstracts" published in association with them, which may be what you have seen in the past.

Neither approach has any particular requirement of credentials: you just need to submit material that is of interest to the community and up to its standards of quality.

Comment: Another possibility: your company can [found its own scientific journal](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/). Not an easy trick to pull off, obviously.